# IntelliJ won't accept FileTypeFactory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am attempting to follow the [Language and File Type tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Language+and+File+Type) for JetBrains IntelliJ

It worked, once. Now (whatever I do) I receive an assertion failure stating that it was expecting an instance of `FileTypeFactory` and got my `SimpleFileTypeFactory`

My `public class SimpleFileTypeFactory extends com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.FileTypeFactory` so I'm not sure how to react to this ...

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: class com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.FileTypeFactory; Actual: class bengie.idea.SimpleFileTypeFactory
  at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.assertClass(ExtensionPointImpl.java:408)
  at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapters(ExtensionPointImpl.java:242)
  at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.getExtensions(ExtensionPointImpl.java:185)
```

... especially when Google has no matches for `"Expected: class com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.FileTypeFactory; Actual"`

Has anyone resolved this sort of thing?

Comment: Can you post your code, and explain what you changed between the first run (that worked), and the subsequent runs (that didn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was depending on a Maven module (actually, two of them) The rest of my project is built with Maven so it seemed logical and looked like it would work. I didn't remember the build seizing up when I added them, so I had forgotten about it. Removing the dependency, starting a debug session, uninstalling the plugin, rinse, repeat and I eventually stopped seeing error messages.

I've since stuffed the maven modules into a `jar-with-dependencies` and told the IntelliJ plugin module to load the resulting `.jar` No problems so far - Yay!